# Ambiguous Truth Value - For Loop & If Statements

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

Chasing the reasoning behind the following error message.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

This is the code I am running:

```
anz_analysis["Action"] = anz_analysis["Signal"]        

for i in range(0, len(anz_analysis) + 1):       
    if ((anz_analysis["Signal"].iloc[[i]] == "Buy") & (anz_analysis["Signal"].iloc[[i+1]] == "Buy")):
        anz_analysis["Action"] = anz_analysis["Signal"].iloc[[i]] = "Maintain"
    elif (anz_analysis["Signal"].iloc[[i]] = "Sell") & (anz_analysis["Signal"].iloc[[i+1]] = "Sell"):
        anz_analysis["Signal"].iloc[[i]] = "Maintain"
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
Current: Wanted: 
_______|_________
1|Buy  | Buy
2|Buy  | Maintain
3|Buy  | Maintain
4|Sell | Sell
5|Sell | Maintain
6|Sell | Maintain
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `elif` clause contains a very suspect `=` that should probably be `==`. Is this really code you copied and pasted or you retyped it in so it may be different from the code you're looking problems in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.iloc[[i]]` returns a `Series`.  So even though there is only one value in the `Series`, that `ValueError` arises, because you are comparing a `Series` to a `str`.

One way to deal with this is to use `.iloc[[i]][0]`.  That will 'extract' the string and allow the comparison to be made between the same types.

A better way would be to select the row and column with `iloc`.  E.g.

```
anz_analysis["Action"] = anz_analysis["Signal"]        

for i in range(len(anz_analysis) + 1):       
    if ((anz_analysis.iloc[i, 'Signal'] == "Buy") & (anz_analysis.iloc[i + 1, 'Signal'] == "Buy")):
        anz_analysis["Action"] = anz_analysis.iloc[i, 'Signal'] = "Maintain"
    elif (anz_analysis.iloc[i, 'Signal'] == "Sell") & (anz_analysis.iloc[i + 1, 'Signal'] == "Sell"):
        anz_analysis.iloc[i, 'Signal'] = "Maintain"
```

**Edit**
Updated the `elif` statement as per @6502's observation of the likely error  in OP's code there.  Also decided to remove the spurious start value of `0` in `range`.